# Steam Login script won´t work

Tags: php, authentication, steam

I tried to use the steam-login script of github on my php file.
I used a custom button instead of the official steam button.
The situation is: I press the button and i get to the standard localhost/dashboard site, I'm simulating it over XAMPP.
Script to login to steam, adding a trade link of your steam account, showing your profile and logging out at the end.

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_SESSION["steamid"])) {
    steamlogin();
    echo '<a class="ezpz-loginas" style="font-size: 12px;border: 2px solid #db073d;margin: 60px auto 0px;padding-top: 22px;" href="/?login">CONNECT TO STEAM</a>';
  } else {
    echo '<article class="jfrs clearfix">
      <img src="' . $steamprofile['avatarfull'] . '" height="74" width="74" alt="">
      <p>' . $steamprofile['personaname'] . ' <a href="steamauth/logout.php">Logout</a></p>
      <ul class="clearfix">
      <li><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/me/tradeoffers/privacy#trade_offer_access_url" target="_blank">Where can I find my Trade-URL?</a></li>
      </ul>
      </article>
      <form method="POST" action="./updatelink.php">
      <input type="text" class="main-link" name="link" id="link" value="' . $mytrade . '" placeholder="Set Trade-URL">
      <input type="submit" class="main-link-check" href="#" value="">
      </form>';

    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name='" . $steamprofile['personaname'] . "', avatar='" . $steamprofile['avatarfull'] . "' WHERE steamid='" . $_SESSION["steamid"] . "'");
  }
?>
```

I edited the steamauth files in the right way.
P.S.: Sorry for my english skills.

Comment: Exactly **HOW** does this "not work"?

Comment: "The situation is: I press the button and i get to the standard localhost/dashboard site, im simulating it over XAMPP"

It should redirect to the steamcommunity where one can login to his account to share his profile information with the site.